# TNS: No listener from other user

Tags: oracle, tnsnames

I'm trying to connect oracle database with non oracle user.

```
sqlplus user/password@sid
```

but it return

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Wed Mar 12 22:34:08 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Enter user-name:
```

but if i try to connect with this line

```
sqlplus user/password
```

the connection was successful, so i need to know how fix it. this not happen with oracle or root users.

if check the port its alive for all users

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.5:1521            0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

UPDATE

tnsnames.ora

```
DBBRM75 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.2.5)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = dbbrm75.local)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.2.5)(PORT = 1521))
```

listener.ora

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = dbbrm75.local)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1)
      (SID_NAME = dbbrm75)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.2.5)(PORT = 1521))
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /opt/app/oracle
```

lsnrctl status

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 12-MAR-2014 23:32:52

Copyright (c) 1991, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.2.5)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                12-MAR-2014 23:20:49
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 12 min. 2 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/vilya/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.2.5)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "dbbrm75.local" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "dbbrm75", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: The first command is trying to use the listener to connect.  The second is not.  Are you sure that the listener is running?  Are you sure that it is listening for this service?  Post your TNS alias (i.e. the `sid` entry from your tnsnames.ora file if you are using local naming) and the output of `lsnrctl status`.

Comment: I edit my post i put my configuration files,

Comment: The listener is running, i don't know if it is listening the service. but if i execute with oracle user or root user the command `sqlplus system/pass@dbbrm75` it is ok, but with the user omj only connect with `sqlplus system/pass`

Comment: I Fix it, installing Oracle Client and changing permissions in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Windows + R (Open Run)
2. Type ---> services.msc
3. Select `OracleServiceXe` or `OracleServiceOrcl` and click on start or restart to start the service
4. Now try with your username/password for SQL Plus